# tb_userspace to auto start?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm using tb_userspace provided by [tb-tun](http://code.google.com/p/tb-tun/) to use HE.net's tunnelbroker service in an openvz vps, but all references and how-tos are telling me to do something like:

`setsid /path/to/tb_userspace ipv6 SERVER.ADDRESS`

I do have this running correctly if I run it in a shell myself, and then bring the interface up and set correct route using `ifconfig`:

```
ifconfig ipv6 up
ifconfig ipv6 inet6 add CLIENT.IP/64
ifconfig ipv6 mtu 1480
route -A inet6 add ::/0 dev ipv6
```

But when I put all of this into /etc/rc.local, strange thing happen: All commands after tb_userspace are ignored and not executed, but the tb_userspace does run correctly. So I have to run the other four commands manually every time after a reboot.

Any suggestion on this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a diagnostic that I often find useful with rc scripts.  Change this:

```
#!/bin/sh

command1
confusing_command2
confusing_command3
```

To:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x
exec > /tmp/rc-stuff.out 2>&1
command1
confusing_command2
confusing_command3
```

...Then after a boot, inspect /tmp/rc-stuff.out to see what's happening during the boot.

...Also, make sure your rc script isn't running forever using the ps command, like "ps axf".

Comment: Argh, thanks! I tried it and it stops at the tb_userspace line, and using `ps axf` shows the script is running forever... but I do not get this result if I run the setsid line in shell myself, what could be problem?